# what's dual of this cone optimization problem, Is it a linear problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, optimal-control

I want to know the dual of this problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_{x,t}f^Tx\\
s.t.&\|A_ix+b_i\|\le c_i^Tx+d_i\quad i=1,\dots,n\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
C_0+\sum_{i=1}^nx_iC_i&Dx\\
x^TD&t
\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In fact, I know the first constraint is the second-order cone, but don't know how to solve the second constraint.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: It is a semidefinite problem. The material in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/duality.html should help you dualize it.